# How do I enable Ratings and Likes for blogs SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, blog

Is there a way to add both **Ratings** and **Likes** in **SharePoint Online Blogs**?

[image]

As of now, the settings page only provides to choose either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can either have one (likes or start ratings) enabled at a time.

Comment: yes, that's the usual case, but is there a way that we can get both ratings and likes at the same time?

Comment: Nothing I am aware of right now but building a custom would be an overkill.